# proper data structure for nested hashes

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is the proper data structure to represent a relationship like below? Am I better of representing this as a tree instead for instance? If so, how would that three look like? My goal is to have instances of class A in memory with the best memory foot print and also fast inserts to any level of the nest.

Each of the nested dictionaries cloud have several millions of items and class E size can be about 10MB per class.

```
    public class A
    {
        private Dictionary<int, B> someName;
    }

    public class B
    {
        private Dictionary<int, C> someName;
    }

    public class C
    {
        private Dictionary<int, D> someName;
    }

    public class D
    {
        private Dictionary<int, E> someName;
    }

    public class E
    {
           //10 Mb worth of properties
    }
```

Comment: What about the range of your int?

Comment: That's random. Any 32 bit int

Answer (score 1):

There are many algorithms and datastructures on external memory, which may contain what you want since your data size is very large.

We commonly use I/O per operation to evaluate the effectiveness of a datastructure when we are dealing with external memory problems.

[image: I/O Model]

You are thinking about representing this as a tree, which I think is a promising solution. Basically, we need a search tree, something like a B-tree. More specifically, a balanced B-tree on external memory.

I think you can use weight-balanced B-tree, which is a combination of B-tree and BB[α]-tree, to solve this problem.

A Weight-balanced B-tree with parameters b and k(b>8,k≥8) holds the following constraints:

1. All leaves on same level and contain between k/4 and k elements.
2. Internal node v at level l has w(v) < b^l * k.
3. Except for the root, internal node v at level l has w(v)> 1/4 * b^l * k.
4. The root has more than one child.

We can infer that internal node degree are between (1/4 * b^l * k) / (b^l*k) = 1/4b and (b^l * k) / (1/4 * b^l-1 * k) = 4b.

The Weight-balanced B-tree with branching parameter b and leaf parameter k=Ω(B) has following properties:

[image: Weight-Balanced B-Tree]

1. Space: O(N/B)
2. Height: O(log(b, N/k))
3. O(log(b, N)) rebalancing operations after an update

The proof is not very complicated and can be seen in [External Memory Geometric Data Structures](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~large/ioS06/ionotes.pdf) written by [Lars Arge](http://cs.au.dk/~large/). The notes on external memory data strucutres is very good and I highly recommend you to read. You can start by reading some of the [lecture notes](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~large/ioS07/) by L.Arge, which can quickly help you to understand this data structure and make your decision.

Comment: Many thanks for the great answer. Buy what if my instance class A could actually fit in memory? Would I still use same data structure?

Comment: I thought you are requesting some data structures to handle a int->E mapping. Then if the data size is very large, this data structure is very good. But I realize you want to remain the int->B(int->C(...)) mapping. Since A single instance of A/B/C/D can fit in memory, I think you can use directly use the code you posted in that question.